# Why is LyX trying to convert every image into eps?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, lyx, eps

I am trying to insert an image into my document. I tried following formats: PNG, JPG, PDF, SVG (using inkscape) and BMP. No matter what I do I get following error:

> LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .eps.

I do not want to include any eps file as I am using pdflatex!

What am I doing wrong? Why is LyX even mentioning eps files?

Edit:

When I try to insert PDF (for the first time) as graphic I get following error:

> No information for converting pdf format files to eps.
>   Define converter in the preferences

Edit:
Win 7 x64 
The latest:
LyX 2.0.2-1
ImageMagick 
MikTeX
Aspell
Ghostscript
GSview

I was able to compile my document using ps2pdf!

Comment: We need to know more. In the Document Settings, what is Default Output Format set to?

Comment: It's set to pdflatex.

Comment: What document style are you using? Is it anything strange with images in?

Comment: article (Polish version by M.W.) Nothing strange until compile, images are visible in LyX. ps2pdf unlike pdflatex does work.

Comment: If ps2pdf works then either you've got `.eps` files, or something is converting them on the fly. More likely the former. The error you quote in the question seems to indicate the former. What do you see if you try to open one of the images in a text editor?

Comment: '‰PNG IHDR  &  7   ťăú   sBIT|d    pHYs  -ü  -ü®Ăě   tEXtSoftware www.inkscape.org›î<    IDAT'...  Exported from inkscape as bitmap.

Comment: Ok, if you know how to run pdflatex without LyX, put the following into a file called `test.tex`, and replace `your_bitmap` with the name of your file. Try it without the file suffix, i.e. `your_bitmap` rather than `your_bitmap.png`: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\begin{document}\includegraphics{errormap}\end{document}
`. Let me know if that gives you a pdf.

Comment: Oh, and make sure they're in the same folder of course.

Comment: Works fine, PDF is created, image is visible. Still, main question remains unsolved.

Comment: Of course, but now it is reduced to LyX.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and my solution was: in "Tools -> Preferences -> Converters" consider the "LaTeX (pdflatex) -> PDF (pdflatex)" converter and set

```
latex=pdflatex
```

in "Extra flag". If this will not work, delete the converters section in your ./lyx/preferences file (in Linux) and restart LyX.

Comment: This is the settings that I have in my Lyx now. any other ides?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Inkscape did not really convert the image to the other formats, but rather only renamed it to another extension. That means, your image.jpg is in fact an EPS file that has a JPG extension. You can verify this under linux if you have [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/mogrify.html) installed, using the command:

`identify image.jpg`

If the line reads `"image PS .... "` instead of `"image JPEG ..."`, then this is indeed the case.

Another way to check if this is the case is by replacing your image for an image that you are sure about is a JPG file (just take a picture or something). If the error does not appear, this issue is most likely related to the image itself.

Comment: I work under windows but I am sure files are not EPS. Especially bitmap ones.

Comment: @Tokamak Hmm OK. Are you trying with the same image, or have you tried a 'proven' image at some point (some other JPG file for instance)? And do you have the same issue with other TeX files, or just this one. I'm just taking shots here, but it can help to isolate where the problem originates exactly.

Comment: I create files using Inkscape. PNG by export to image other as regular save as. I tried MS Paint for png too. I didn't really used TEX previously. And even if I did, only for some equations without graphics. I updated some information in other posts.

Comment: If you create the files with Inkscape, export as PDF. Not only does this work with `pdflatex` (or at least it should), but you also keep it a vector image.

Comment: As is stated in question: I already tried PDF.